# How to configure PostgreSQL database for deploying alfresco on tomcat 8?

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, alfresco

I have built alfresco(version 5.2) from source on ubuntu 16.04. I want to deploy alfresco on tomcat 8. The deployment is successful however the PostgreSQL database is not getting configured as required. I have followed the steps as given in http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/postgresql-config.html

I observe the home page as [given in image alfresco_page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QblSH.jpg)

Am I missing onto something here that the PostgreSQL database is not getting configured. Is there any other configuration that needs to be done that I have missed ?

**UPDATE**

The alfresco.log gave me this

```
2017-08-01 05:53:54,406 WARN  [org.alfresco.web.scripts.servlet.X509ServletFilterBase] [localhost-startStop-1] clientAuth does not appear to be set for Tomcat. clientAuth must be set to 'want' for X509 Authentication
2017-08-01 05:53:54,416 WARN  [org.alfresco.web.scripts.servlet.X509ServletFilterBase] [localhost-startStop-1] Attempting to set clientAuth=want through JMX...
2017-08-01 05:53:54,427 WARN  [org.alfresco.web.scripts.servlet.X509ServletFilterBase] [localhost-startStop-1] Unable to set clientAuth=want through JMX.
2017-08-01 05:53:55,139 ERROR [org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer] [coreLoadExecutor-5-thread-1] Error creating core [collection1]: Could not load conf for core collection1: Error loading solr config from solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core collection1: Error loading solr config from solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml
        at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:66)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:489)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:249)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading solr config from solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.readFromResourceLoader(SolrConfig.java:154)
        at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createSolrConfig(ConfigSetService.java:80)
        at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:61)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/root/tomcat85/output/build/webapps/solr/collection1/conf'
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:362)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openConfig(SolrResourceLoader.java:308)
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:117)
        at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:87)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.<init>(SolrConfig.java:167)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.readFromResourceLoader(SolrConfig.java:145)
        ... 9 more
2017-08-01 05:54:09,634 WARN  [org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Could not obtain connection metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2079)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1304)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:863)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:782)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
```

Comment: As the error says, did you create an `alfresco-global.properties` file and correctly configure your posgres database in that?

Comment: yes. i have updated alfresco-global.properties file as per instructions given in http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/postgresql-config.html still I am getting same error page

Comment: @Aditya Were you able to perform all the steps successfully in the links you mentioned, without any errors? We can also see errors related to `solrconfig.xml`, were you able to resolve those?

Comment: @phoenixSid there is no solrconfig.xml file that has been created. Also, i could perform those steps but did not get any error other than mentioned in alfresco.log file above.

Comment: @Aditya What are the values set for the db.host and db.port? And I am assuming that the port is not blocked on your machine.

Comment: @phoenixSid db.host=localhost and db.port=5432 and yes, port is not blocked.

Comment: @Aditya As mentioned by @Gagravarr, there seems to be some problem with the `alfresco-global.properties`. Please double check your configuration.

Comment: @ phoenixSid thanks but I am unable to find out the cause. Actually i have copied alfresco source from directory https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/5.2.f/  and built it using maven.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. Is postgres running (ps -ef|grep postgres)?
2. Can you use psql to connect to postgres using the db.name, db.username, and db.password that are configured in alfresco-global.properties?
3. Did you follow the step in the docs about editing pg_hba.conf to make sure that postgres is configured to allow password based authentication?

Also, it is exceedingly rare to need to build Alfresco from source unless you are making changes to the low-level classes themselves, which is not recommended.